# How do I install StringUtils plugin in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

How do I install StringUtils plugin in Eclipse ?

here is the link: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/stringutils-plugin

This plug-in has some strange behaviour. It's not in the marketplace, nor in "install new software' the initial page doesn't have any install or download button.

I found this page here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsestringutils/?source=typ_redirect

that has a download option, but if I try to install it on "install new software" option it says it can't find the "artifacts.jar" file, even if file permissions are all ok.

I'm using Eclipse Mars.

Comment: Read the Eclipse Wiki FAQs https://wiki.eclipse.org/Category:FAQ -  [FAQ How do I install new plug-ins?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_install_new_plug-ins%3F)

Comment: well I guess that's my fault. I really didn't give any clue that I know the normal procedures and if can't install the plug-in is because there's something wrong with it. Complemented the question.